# django rest framework deserialize by name

Tags: python, django, deserialization, django-rest-framework

I would like to be able to have the Django REST Framework de-serialize data which could arrive in two slightly different forms outlined below. I think I could do this be overriding the restore_fields method within the NodeGroupSerializer class, but that feels SO wrong. I don't want to do it that way. I expect I've missed something in the documentation about this situation, any pointers appreciated.

Models

```
class NodeGroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = NodeGroup
    depth = 3

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Service


class EnvironmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Environment
```

Serialized:

```
{
    "environment": {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/environments/1/", 
        "name": "Development", 
    }, 
    "service": {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/services/144/", 
        "name": "testservice", 
    }, 
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/nodegroups/1/", 
    "domain": "test.cloud.com", 
    "hieradata": ""
}
```

I would like to be able to also de-serialize requests the form below, where the environment and service can be looked up by the name value which I know to be unique. How could I get the serializer class to check the request values and do a lookup where needed?

Additional form required to be de-serialized:

```
{
    "environment": "Development", 
    "service": "testservice", 
    "domain": "test.cloud.com", 
    "hieradata": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `get_serializer_class` in your view.
[docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views)